# Allow only network connections but not connect to internet

Tags: networking, network-manager, traceroute

I can do this by going to the network manager

edit connections > myconn > ipv4 > routes

and check
"*use this connection only for resources on its network*"

all this without inputing my sudoer password, how can I do the same in command line mode? without sudo if possible! thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ip` command for setting up routes. You basically need to remove your default route. At make sure you have a route entry into your local network.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it but I had to use sudo, it would be nice to know how the Ubuntu GUI does it without prompting for a password.

For example if my network IP is 192.168.1.101 by doing:

```
sudo ip route delete default
```

I can access to 192.168.1.0/24 network

If I want to enable "internet" again, being my router 192.168.1.1 I just do:

```
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1
```